# Azure SQL Down?

Tags: azure

OK so anybody know what I supposed to do?

Thanks
Pat NH USA

• Some features are not currently available for the server 'xbypev8j5v' in subscription xxxxxxxxx since the server information could not be retrieved at the moment. Please wait a few minutes and then try this operation again.
The databases for server xbypev8j5v located in region South Central US for subscription 7xxxxxxxxxxxxx could not be retrieved. Please wait a few minutes and then try this operation again. For more information about Windows Azure service availability, visit the Windows Azure Service Dashboard.[image]

Comment: We are not Azure tech support...

Comment: I was asking if anybody knew what to do..

Comment: @PatTormey the error message tells you what to do.  go to the service dashboard.  that page has a link to contact tech support

Answer (score 2):

> For more
>   information about Windows Azure service availability, visit the
>   Windows Azure Service Dashboard.

That would be http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/service-dashboard/

Comment: And they have now updated the service dashboard - "We are experiencing an issue with SQL Databases in South Central US. We are actively investigating this issue and assessing its impact to our customers. Further updates will be published to keep you apprised of the impact. We apologize for any inconvenience this causes our customers."